# Jquery/Ajax post vars

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i need help with a script, i dont know what is wrong but i think its here:

```
$.post("chatSend.php", {text: text, nome: nome,},
```

but i dont know how to fix it.

Full code:

```
  //Script para enviar e fazer descer a barra quand submited
 $(function(){
 var keyStop = {
   8: ":not(input:text, textarea, input:file, input:password)", // stop backspace = back
   13: "input:text, input:password", // stop enter = submit 

   end: null
 };
 $(document).bind("keydown", function(event){
  var selector = keyStop[event.which];

  if(selector !== undefined && $(event.target).is(selector)) {
  var text = $("#text");
  var nome = $("#nome");
        var text = text.val(); 
        var nome = nome.val();

        $.post("chatSend.php", {text: text, nome: nome,},

        function(data){
         $('#chat').load('getChat.php');
         $('#chat').animate({scrollTop: '30000px'}, 1000);
         $("input[type='text']").val('');
         }
         , "html");
      event.preventDefault(); //stop event
  }
  return true;
 });
});
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use    `$.post("chatSend.php", {text: text, nome: nome},` instead of `$.post("chatSend.php", {text: text, nome: nome,},`

Comment: isnt sending to DB :s
if i use only text val it works..

I will post chatSend.php and the form

chatSend.php(its working only with text value):

    $user = $_POST['nome'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_chat (user, message) VALUES('$user', '$text')");

Form:

    <form action="" method="post" form="form">
         <input type="text" id="text" name="text" class="sendText" /><br />
      <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="sendText"/>
     </form>

Thanks again!!